# How to save a record associated with multiple user in Mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

My Schemas are: Schema for User

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var userSchema = new Schema({
    name:String,
    mobile:String,
    meals:[{type:Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Meal'}],
    deposits:[{type:Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Deposit'}],
    costs:[{type:Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Cost'}]
},
{ 
    usePushEach: true 
});

var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
module.exports = User;
```

Schema for Costs

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var costSchema = new Schema({
    persons:[{type:Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}],
    amount:Number,
    date:{type:Date, default:Date.now},
    market:String,
    costType:String
},
{ 
   usePushEach: true 
});

var Cost = mongoose.model("Cost", costSchema);
module.exports = Cost;
```

The problem is, How to save the Costs

```js
app.post('/cost', adminPass, (req, res)=>{
    User.find({}, (err, user)=>{
        let data= {
            date:req.body.date,
            amount:req.body.amount,
            market:req.body.market,
            costType:req.body.costType
         };
        let id1=req.body.id1, id2=req.body.id2;
        Cost.create(data, (err, cost)=>{
            if(err){console.log(err);}
            cost.persons.push(id1);
            cost.persons.push(id2);
            cost.save();
            user.costs.push(cost);
            user();
            console.log(cost);
            res.redirect('/cost');
        });
    });
});
```

Most of other things is working pretty fine but the problem with adding persons to each cost record and also pushing that record to the user record. for further details please comment. I am getting this error.

```
{ 
  _id: 5b58056c63eca912f43e370f,
  amount: 1000,
  market: 'অন্যান্য',
  costType: 'Grocery',
  __v: 0,
  date: 2018-07-27T00:00:00.000Z,
  persons: [] }
E:\File\Practice\node.js\scs\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:98
     process.nextTick(function() { throw err; });
                              ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
```

Comment: What error are you getting? And what mongoose version are you using?

Comment: thanks @MrcRjs `"mongoose": "5.2.4", `

Comment: error `_id: 5b58056c63eca912f43e370f,
  amount: 1000,
  market: 'অন্যান্য',
  costType: 'Grocery',
  __v: 0,
  date: 2018-07-27T00:00:00.000Z,
  persons: [] }
E:\File\Practice\node.js\scs\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:98
    process.nextTick(function() { throw err; });
                                  ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined`

Comment: I have edited the main question with my error

Answer (score 0):

Your Costs Schema needs a default value for persons, set it default to [], that's why you get the undefined error.